# Connecting Odoo 12 error via xmlrpc library

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have below simple program to connect odoo 12 on my local system. I am getting a below-mentioned error. Please advise.

```
import xmlrpc.client
import csv

server = "http://localhost:8069"
database = "dietfacts2"
user = "admin"
pwd = "admin"


common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(server))
print("Version Details: " , common.version())


uid = common.authenticate(database, user, pwd, {})
print(uid)
```

**Below is the error:**

> Version Details:  {'server_version': '12.0', 'server_version_info':
>   [12, 0, 0, 'final', 0, ''], 'server_serie': '12.0',
>   'protocol_version': 1}
>
> xmlrpc.client.Fault: 
>   return func(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__\n    a
>   = self.d[obj].me\nKeyError: \'dietfacts2\'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent
>   call last):\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 63, in
>   xmlrpc_2\n    response = self._xmlrpc(service)\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 43, in
>   _xmlrpc\n    result = dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 120, in dispatch_rpc\n
>   result = dispatch(method, params)\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/service/common.py", line 61, in dispatch\n
>   return gexp_method_name\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/service/common.py", line 30, in
>   exp_authenticate\n    res_users = odoo.registry(db)[\'res.users\']\n 
>   File "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 117, in registry\n
>   return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__\n
>   return cls.new(db_name)\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new\n
>   registry.setup_signaling()\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 361, in
>   setup_signaling\n    cr.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE
>   base_registry_signaling INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1")\n  File
>   "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 148, in wrapper\n    return
>   f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/home/odoodev/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py",
>   line 225, in execute\n    res = self._obj.execute(query,
>   params)\npsycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation
>   "base_registry_signaling" already exists\n\n'>

**Main Error**
**npsycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists**